# Differences in importing javascript libraries between Angular 5 and 6 - which is the right syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to import **lodash** into an Angular component.

In **Angular 6** it seems I can use both of the following syntaxes

```
// either
import _ from 'lodash';
// or
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

In **Angular 5** it seems that only the second works. If I use the first one, `_` is just `undefined`.

Which is the reason for the different behavior?

Comment: that should depend on whether lodash has a default export and have nothing to do with angular. See the related [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) about javascript export/import.

Comment: if you enable `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in your `tsconfig.json`in your angular 5 project it should work with the short syntax too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my point is that apparently the 2 syntaxes work in **Angular 6** while only one works in **Angular 5** - this is what happens at least on my installation - `lodash` is at the same version in both cases

Comment: @mtizziani  - it does not work, unfortunately - thanks anyways

Comment: @Picci ok. i did not test it in angular context. in my vanilla ts project it works